# Skrollr weird issue on mobile

Tags: mobile, parallax, skrollr

I checked a bit everywhere on internet but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Skrollr is not working properly on mobile on my page : http://ocelyn.com/travel/tism/
I tried to put a #skrollr-body element a bit everywhere in my page but I always get an issue. Do you have any idea why this issue?

I'm using the last version of Skrollr.

Best,

Jocelyn

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix most of the issue by myself, now Skrollr works but when I try to scroll to the bottom it will stop at some point same as it was missing some pixels to reach the bottom.

I'm not sure but I think it's the equivalent of the height of the screen.

If you have some idea I would appreciate to hear about it,

UPDATE 14/09/05, finally I found a dirty way to fix this issue :

```
setTimeout(function(){      
            skrollr.refresh(document.body);
        },400);
```

I just force skrollr to refresh after the loading of the page and it's fine.

Best,

Jocelyn